# Delimited Function in SQL to Split Data between semi-colon

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, split

I have the data below.

[image: Original Data]

I'm only interested on program B. How do I change it into the table below using SQL syntax?

[image: Program B Only]

Below is my syntax but it doesn't give me what I want.

```
SELECT
  SUBSTRING(Program, 0, CHARINDEX(';', Program)),
  SUBSTRING(
      SUBSTRING(Program, CHARINDEX(';', Program) + 1, LEN(Program)),
      0,
      CHARINDEX(';', SUBSTRING(Program, CHARINDEX(';', Program) + 1,
                               LEN(Program)))),
  REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(Program), 0, CHARINDEX(';', REVERSE(Program)))),
  File_Count
FROM DataBase1
WHERE Program LIKE '%B%'
```

Thanks guys for your help.

Adhi

Comment: Which kind of database do you use? In the one program cell may be several values of B?

Comment: I'm using Microsoft SQL 2012. Yes there are several values of B in different cells. They are not the same.

Comment: By the way, thanks PM. for editing my question. It is my first time posting =D. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%B[0-9][0-9]%', Program)>0 THEN SUBSTRING(Program, PATINDEX('%B[0-9][0-9]%', Program) - 1, 4) 
     WHEN PATINDEX('%B[0-9]%', Program)>0 THEN SUBSTRING(Program, PATINDEX('%B[0-9]%', Program) - 1, 3) 
     ELSE '' END

FROM DataBase1
```

First `WHEN` is responsible for extracting pattern `B[0-9][0-9]`, i.e. when B is followed by two digits, second one is for extracting B followed by one digits. Default is returning empty string, when no match is found. If you are interested in extracting pattern B followed by three digits, you need to add another when (as the first case), enter pattern `B[-9][0-9][0-9]` instead of `B[0-9][0-9]` and change last number from 4 to 5 (length of string that is extracted).

`PATINDEX` returns position where the match is found.

Comment: Awesome !! Thanks Michal. IT WORKS !!! What about if there are more than one B in a cell, for example, C1;D1;A4;B10;B11 how do you separate B10;B11? Using your syntax, they are kept together. Thanks again for your help. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

If you use PostgreSql you can try next solution.

First create temp table with data:

```
CREATE TABLE temp.test AS (
  SELECT 'A1, B1' AS program, 1 AS file_count
  UNION
  SELECT 'B2', 1
  UNION
  SELECT 'A2, B3', 1
  UNION
  SELECT 'B4', 1
  UNION
  SELECT 'A3, B5', 2
  UNION
  SELECT 'B6', 2
  UNION
  SELECT 'B7', 2
  UNION
  SELECT 'B8', 1
  UNION
  SELECT 'B9', 1
  UNION
  SELECT 'C1;D1;A4;B10', 1
  UNION
  SELECT 'C2;D2;B11', 1
  UNION
  SELECT 'C3,D3,A5,B12', 1
  UNION
  SELECT 'C4;B14;D4;B11,B13', 1
);
```

I suggested that in one program cell can contains several B values (last select).

After that use `regexp_matches` to find all B in cell and select for each `file_count` value(first inner select) and after that sum by each of program:

```
SELECT
  b_program,
  sum(file_count)
FROM (
       SELECT
         (SELECT regexp_matches(program, 'B\d+')) [1] AS b_program,
         file_count
       FROM temp.test
       WHERE upper(program) LIKE '%B%') bpt
GROUP BY b_program
ORDER BY b_program;
```

Comment: Thanks HAYmbl4 for your help. I will keep this syntax in my paper for my future reference. Really appreciate it.